# How to test method with reflect?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a method Sync() that overrides `Config` field's values that are set in the environment.
The environment variable names are derived from config fields by underscoring, and uppercasing the name. E.g. AppName will have a corresponding environment variable APP_NAME

Please help me to test the following cases. There are complex things like https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set:

> Set assigns x to the value v. It panics if CanSet returns false. As in
>   Go, x's value must be assignable to v's type.

So I don't know how to test this case?

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
     "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"
    "github.com/fatih/camelcase"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
    AppName   string 
    BaseURL   string 
    Port      int    
    Verbose   bool   
    StaticDir string 
    ViewsDir  string 
}

func (c *Config) Sync() error {
    cfg := reflect.ValueOf(c).Elem()
    cTyp := cfg.Type()

    for k := range make([]struct{}, cTyp.NumField()) {
        field := cTyp.Field(k)

        cm := getEnvName(field.Name)
        env := os.Getenv(cm)
        if env == "" {
            continue
        }
        switch field.Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            cfg.FieldByName(field.Name).SetString(env)
        case reflect.Int:
            v, err := strconv.Atoi(env)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("loading config field %s %v", field.Name, err)
            }
            cfg.FieldByName(field.Name).Set(reflect.ValueOf(v))
        case reflect.Bool:
            b, err := strconv.ParseBool(env)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("loading config field %s %v", field.Name, err)
            }
            cfg.FieldByName(field.Name).SetBool(b)
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test changes made to `Cofig` after calling `Sync`, in your tests define a function that sets the environment:

```
func SetTestEnv(key, value string) error; err != nil {
    if err := os.Setenv(key, value string) {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now in you test function for `Sync`, create a test config, initialize test environment using the above method and call `Sync` on the config value. `strconv` defines `NumError` specifically for failed conversions. You can make use of that:

```
func TestSync(t *testing.T) {
    c : Config{ 
        // initialize config, or do it through another method
        // e.g. func InitConfig(...) *Config {..}
    }

    // set the environment
    SetTestEnv("APP_NAME", "app name")
    SetTestEnv("BASE_URL", "base url")
    SetTestEnv("PORT", "port number") // will cause error
    // etc..

    if err := c.Sync(); err != nil {
        e, ok := err.(*strconv.NumError)
        if !ok {
            t.Errorf("Unexpected error")
        } else if e.Err != strconv.ErrSyntax { // check specifically for expected syntax error
            t.Errorf("Expected conversion to fail")
        }

    }

    SetTestEnv("PORT", "1000") // correct port number

    if err := c.Sync(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Unexpected error in Sync: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Since you are ensuring `Set` is called with correct value type using type switches, there should not be any cause for panic to occur.

Comment: I want to test if code works when there is an error in  `v, err := strconv.Atoi(env)` inside the Sync() method

Comment: Like mentioned above, `SetTestEnv("PORT", "any string")` sets the port number to a string that cannot be converted to a number. In this case, calling `Sync` would result is an error that the first `if` in the test function is testing.